# Why does Flask-Compress not work on AWS EC2?

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, gzip

I have a flask app, that used flack-compress json and js files. The Gzip compression works fine, when run on a local machine, but when deployed on a AWS AMI1 EC2 instance, the compression are not working. The files are served at their full size. Tried googling, couldn't find any leads.

Comment: [Flask-Compress is not maintained](https://github.com/jmcarp/flask-compress/commits/master) for a quite long time, are you sure you want to use such a lib?

Comment: @fian I'm open for an alternative

Comment: Best practice is to gzip response with a reverse-proxy web-server like Nginx or Apache, which can be used on EC2.